# How do you run and compile C++ code on alpine linux?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, clang++, alpine-linux

I’m new to alpine linux, and I’ve been trying to use it to run and compile C++ code, but I can’t get it to run the code.
First, I put the code in the opt folder, than I did this:

> cd / → cd opt → clang++ -S -emit-llvm myFile.cpp

That created myFile in the opt folder, then I tried to use

> sh myFile

To run the code, but it said “no such file or directory found,” If I do sh myFile.cpp, I get a few errors.

What am I doing wrong here?
Some of the packages I have installed are build-base, and clang.

Comment: ***I put the code in the opt folder,*** That is not a place I would expect to put your code. `/home/myusername/mycodefoldername` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't think alpine versus any other distribution of linux makes any difference.

Comment: `sh myFile.cpp` your c++ file is not an executable program

Comment: Do a `ls -al` in the folder. Is there a `myFile`

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your code in `/opt`, put it somewhere in your home directory. Next, why are you using those `clang++` flags? It should be something like `clang++ myFile.cpp -o foo`. Then you can run the resulting file (`foo`) using `./foo`.

Comment: `cd / → cd opt` BTW, you did not need 2 cd commands. `cd /opt` would have been enough

Answer (score 0):

By default, the result of `clang` (`clang++` as well) is saved to `a.out` file, so you may run `./a.out` or `sh a.out`. If you want to change output, use `-o <filename>` in clang command